# Tagging for Make/Model/Year specific questions?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I have started to see a trend emerge that folks are asking questions and tagging them with Make, model and year as separate tags.  Should this practice be continued, or should we combine tags like "subaru-impreza" instead of "subaru" and "impreza" as seperate tags.

I can see advantages and disadvantages to each approach.  There is a limit to 5 tags per question, so the fewer tags needed, the better.

Comment: How many model names are used by more than one maker?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can make a case for either separate tags ("subaru" and "impreza") or a combined tag ("subaru-impreza"). Most people seem to be tagging the make/model separately so let's go with those.

**But I cannot see a purpose for the year tags.** They should be removed.

Tags should be able to stand on their own and still make sense. A tag "1997" does not mean anything by itself. If a tag does not mean anything by itself, it should be removed. That level of detail should be included in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting assessment, @Robert, if you've ever owned a 1968 Ford Thunderbird and have tried to find information related to the cars, you would know that anything from 1967 to 1971 of that make/model will likely apply.

Most sites where I've tried to find information, it's extremely difficult to locate specific information on `Ford + Thunderbird + [1967|1968|1969|1970|1971]`, generally, on Google, my results span from Ford trucks to 1981 Thunderbirds to transmission sales for Ford Tempos.

I see your point about tags standing on their own, but how can we more easily target the questions and answers so that if I want to find information on only 1967-1971 Ford Thunderbirds, I can instantly narrow my search to that make and model and year range?

What do you suggest?  Am I perhaps misinterpreting the purpose of this site?  I picture a site where one can find answers to specific, expert level problems for the specific vehicle in question.

Comment: Searching for car information by year is tricky. Each model has periodic major revisions, so anything within a certain year range will be relevant for you, but I don't know any good way to tag for that.

Comment: It seems like the site wasn't designed for this level of tagging.  If anyone has any ideas, perhaps a StackApp or some technique for narrowing a search, that would be awesome!

Comment: Great suggestion. The 67-71 Thunderbirds, or fifth gen as you mentioned, is the Glamourbird generation. But are people more likely to search by generation or by year? I think I'm more inclined to search by year.