# Eliminating Year Tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

I only see it once in a while, but would like to ensure an elimination trend continues. Back in [this Meta post](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8/4152) it was suggested and agreed to the "year tag" should be eliminated. I do not believe having a year in the tags helps with the meta discovery of any given vehicle and ultimately wastes one of the five meta tag slots. If you see a tag being used as such, I'd recommend editing the posts (or tags) and eliminating the tag from the post altogether. This will help to keep the tags clean as well as discourage others from using/making year tags.

By year tag, I mean [2007](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2007) or [1996](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1996). In and of itself is a very non-descriptive tag and has been fleshed out before, it fairly useless. The reason I posted this in Meta is I see it every once in a while, so would like to reinforce the guideline which was setup at the beginning of the Beta for Mech.SE. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Useless tags be gone. :)

Comment: @anonymous2 - That's the post I have linked in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Great point, @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2.  I might beg to add that if you do edit a year tag out, please make sure you add the year to the post somewhere else.  It makes a huge difference, for instance, if we are talking about the electric systems on a 1979 Volkswagen Jetta or a 2012 Volkswagen Jetta.  So please, PLEASE edit it either into the title or onto the type of the vehicle, wherever that latter may be in the post.

Comment: Agreed. Don't get rid of the info, just the tag. It has so much more value in the body.